# Java Method returns null-value

Tags: java, methods

I have the following method, which iterates map and, based on the result of iterations, assigns the values for local variable DepartmentsFilter departmentsFilter2.
Debugging each line of this expression, I see, that, while iteration proceeds, departmentsFilter2 get values.  But on return-stage it become null.

```
private DepartmentsFilter getDepartmentFilter(Map<String, Object> parameters, 
FilterBuilder<DepartmentsFilter> builder) {
    DepartmentsFilter departmentsFilter2 = new DepartmentsFilter(null, null, null, null, null);
    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : parameters.entrySet()) {
        departmentsFilter2 = (DepartmentsFilter) builder.buildFilter(entry, departmentsFilter2);
    }
    return departmentsFilter2;
}
```

Comment: Does the last invocation of `builder.buildFilter(entry, departmentsFilter2)` return null?

Comment: No, it does not return null

Comment: That would be the only way `departmentsFilter2` can become null at the end of the iteration.

Comment: You are rigth. I chcked - the last iteration return null-value

Comment: Wanna close your question now since you've figured out the problem?

Answer (score 1):

For each entry in the map, you are currently over-writing `departmentsFilter2`. The return value you get is corresponding to the last entry in the map, which must be producing a null `departmentsFilter2`.

If you want the full list, save each `departmentsFilter2` into a list and then return the list instead.

Comment: You are rigth. I chcked - the last iteration return null-value